# CSS file ignored after modification

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to override the following bootstrap value

```
.table > thead > tr > td.danger, .table > tbody > tr > td.danger, .table > tfoot > tr > td.danger, .table > thead > tr > th.danger, .table > tbody > tr > th.danger, .table > tfoot > tr > th.danger, .table > thead > tr.danger > td, .table > tbody > tr.danger > td, .table > tfoot > tr.danger > td, .table > thead > tr.danger > th, .table > tbody > tr.danger > th, .table > tfoot > tr.danger > th {
background-color: #f2dede;
}
```

So I have created my own CSS file with the following

```
.myhead {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

Here the HTML

```
<tr class="danger">
    <th class="myhead" nowrap="nowrap">Test</th>

</tr>
```

Now in order to increase the specificity to win over the bootstrap value I have decided to amend CSS as follow

```
.myhead, #myhead1, #myhead2, #myhead3, #myhead4 {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

The problem when I do that is that the browser completely ignore the CSS file, I can't even see my "myhead" class when I inspect the page. Previously when I inspected the file I could clearly see my CSS files taken into account but the property was overridden (strike-through) by bootstrap.

What is the issue here?

UPDATE: Updated with coma as advised by Berendschot, I can now see my CSS file back but still I can't override bootstarp. Acording to my calculation I should have a priority of 410 (10 + 100 + 100 + 100 + 100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use comma's to separate classes and id's in CSS.

The styles in `.myhead #myhead1 #myhead2 #myhead3 #myhead4` will only be applied to elements who have all these classes and id's. By adding comma's the styles will be applied to all elements who have at least one of them.

> **Example:** `div, p` Selects all `<div>` elements and all `<p>` elements.

**More on** [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

---

If you want to override a certain style, you have to make sure that you embed the class after the first declaration, or use `!important`.

**More about using** [`!important`](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/).

Comment: Important is working but as I sais in my update above I though that I would get 410 point with the syntax with the commas thus overriding boostrap. Still if I don't use important it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the original CSS, but you might want to add `!important`to your CSS rule to override other classes:

```
.myhead, #myhead1, #myhead2, #myhead3, #myhead4 {
    background-color: blue !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector relationship `.myhead #myhead1 #myhead2 #myhead3 #myhead4` how it's written is expecting that `#myhead4` is a child of `#myhead3`, and `#myhead3` is a child of `#myhead2`, etc.... If this isn't the case in your document, the style will never be used.

```
<th class="myhead">
  <div id="myhead1">
   <div id="myhead2">
    <div id="myhead3">
     <div id="myhead4">This would have a blue background with white text</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
<th>
```

Using `!important` is useful in some scopes, but issues can come from it and can sometimes be difficult to debug. My suggestion for your markup;

```
<tr class="danger">
    <th class="myhead" nowrap="nowrap">Test</th>
</tr>
```

Use selector.class { ... } Like this.

```
th.myhead {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

This way all `<th>` elements with the class of `myhead` will use the style declared. `ID`s are unique on each page so it's not necessary and can be defined as just #id1, #id2, etc... Hope this helps.